# Connecting Google REST API through my REST API is not working

Tags: php, web-services, api, codeigniter, rest

I have this application with the below structure
[image]

I am using **rest client library** https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient  to connect to **MyAPI** and using **php api client**  http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ to connect to **Google API**

my Controller code is as below

```
 function index()
    {
        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
           $logged = $this->rest->get('auth/user',array(
               'email'=>$this->input->post('email')
                   )); 
           var_dump($logged);
        }
        $this->load->view('layout/login',$this->data);
    }
```

and my API code that handle this request is as below which make sure that user exist in my database and authenticated through Google as well

```
function user_get()
    {
        $response=NULL;
        $data=array(
            'email'=>$this->get('email')
        );
        $google_account=$this->google->authenticate();
        if(  isset($google_account) && $this->user_model->login($data))
        {
            $response->status='success';
            $response->message=$google_account;
        }
        else
        {
            $response->status='error';
            $response->message='Failed to authenticate user';   
        }
        $this->response($response,200);
    }
```

and `Google` library function `Authenticate' is as below

```
function authenticate()
    {
        $oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($this->client);
        if (isset($_GET['code']))
        {
            $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            $_SESSION['token'] = $this->client->getAccessToken();
            $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
            header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
            return;
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) 
        {
            $this->client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        }
        if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) 
        {
            unset($_SESSION['token']);
            $this->client->revokeToken();
        }
        if ($this->client->getAccessToken()) 
        {
            $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
            // The access token may have been updated lazily.
            $_SESSION['token'] = $this->client->getAccessToken();
            return $user;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $authUrl = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
            redirect($authUrl);
        }

    }
```

**problem is** 
When i connect this throught browser with direct url 
`http://localhost/hac_dc/api/auth/user/ahmed.samy.cs@gmail.com`
i get JSON response perfectly

but when i connect it using rest client

i get response `false` I have tried change the way i use my rest client i tried to add third parameter as `JSON` and as MIME `application/json` but didnt work out

I dunno if it's problem or bad practice to connect another REST API though my REST API,

been pulling my hair for hours please help me on this

Comment: What is the REST client you've been using?

Comment: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your REST client doesn't handle the oauth authentication, does it? 
I assume you shall authenticate your REST client somehow to let it use the access token delivered by Google.

To do so manually, you might save once the access token you've received from Google to a datastore when accessing your API manually (using your browser for instance and by inspecting your browser session). Having this access token available, you could then restore a valid session for your REST client.

Authenticating your REST client towards Google, can be done using cURL or reusing some existing library such as https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth2.git. To authenticate your REST client towards your own API, you could use HTTP basic/digest authentication (as suggested by CodeIgniter-REST client) after having added an authentication extra-layer to your api (if it is missing).

P.S. When authenticating your user, in case of failure, the 401 response status code might be more legit (see also http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2)

Comment: I am using rest client connect my API but when connecting Google I m using google API that support oauth 2.0

Comment: So your own application (embedding an API) does authenticate itself towards Google using its OAuth API? Have you checked the authentication status of your application when connecting to your own API using your rest client? Perhaps you could provide an endpoint informing your REST Client about the OAuth authentication status of your app towards Google API to ensure this is fully covered?

Comment: Yes I m using oauth and Google API is connecting normally from CI controller but not from Rest API controller

Comment: So I'm afraid you might have to switch from your current REST client to another one supporting OAauth authentication.

Answer (score 0):

problem is cross domain request error. You can connect

> localhost/hac_dc/api/auth/user/ahmed.samy.cs@gmail.com

because your server performs as web proxy. but you can't do it directly via REST with simple getJSON technique. you can use JSONP in jquery ajax,it's 100% working for cross domain. JSONP is not JSON, it returns js function call to callback method with JSON parameter.you can achieve in following ajax call. But there is no 'success' callback in JSONP and for this purpose you must supply callback parameter in ajax call and define that callback function.

```
$.ajax({
       crossDomain: true,
       type:"GET",
       contentType: "text; charset=utf-8",
       url: YOUR_URL + "&callback=mycallback",
        jsonp:'jsonp',
       dataType: "jsonp"
       });
function mycallback(result){
    //your callback operation
}
```